# bootstrap input forms alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying  to create a data entry form using bootstrap and forms input.

It seems to work well until on some lines it puts one entry on the line instead of 3.

I have tried various routes and always see this behavior.

Any help at understanding why it is doing this wound be greatly appreciated.
I have a plunker example [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/cun1nRC5nSXybAGOM4Hy?p=preview)

```
<fieldset class="scheduler-border well">
  <legend class="scheduler-border">Customer</legend> 
  <form class="form-group" role="form">
    <div class="form-group left">      
      <label for="input16" class="col-md-2 control-label">Label A</label>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="Label A" placeholder="Label A">
      </div>
      <label for="input17" class="col-md-2 control-label">Customer Label ALpha Beta</label>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="Customer Label ALpha Beta" placeholder="Customer Label ALpha Beta">
      </div>
      <label for="input18" class="col-md-2 control-label">Label C</label>        
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="Label C" placeholder="Label C">
      </div>
      <label for="input15" class="col-md-2 control-label">Label D</label>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="Label AD" placeholder="Label D">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</fieldset>
```

If you the launch the preview window and increase the `width` you should be able to see the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if this is what you want, but I guess what you mean is that for some screen sizes *Label D* ends up on the fourth column while it should be on the first. The problem here is that your label *Customer Label Alpha Beta* takes up too much height and since bootstrap's column are just a clever usage of `float:left`, *Label D* will be to the right of it.

The easiest way to adjust your code is to wrap groups of 3 labels/inputs in a `.row` to clear the floats once a row is full.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<fieldset class="scheduler-border well">
  <legend class="scheduler-border">Customer</legend>
  <form class="form-group" role="form">

    <div class="form-group left container">
      <div class="row">
        <label for="input16" class="col-md-2 control-label">Label A</label>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="Label A" placeholder="Label A">
        </div>
        <label for="input17" class="col-md-2 control-label">Customer Label ALpha Beta</label>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="Customer Label ALpha Beta" placeholder="Customer Label ALpha Beta">
        </div>

        <label for="input18" class="col-md-2 control-label">Label C</label>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="Label C" placeholder="Label C">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <label for="input15" class="col-md-2 control-label">Label D</label>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="Label AD" placeholder="Label D">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </form>
</fieldset>
```

Of course this solution isn't prefect, for example your rows might end up with different vertical distances. Maybe getting rid of the `-col-*` and using the classes `.form-inline` or `.form-horizontal will work better for you.